# PHP array_map() and mysqli_real_escape_string()

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to clean all the data before they will be sent to the database (in each database connection)

```php
if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $_GET = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_GET);
    $_POST = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_COOKIE);
 }
```

The Code above gives me the below error error

`mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

Anyone knows a better way of achieving this?

Comment: You should just use a prepared statement instead of using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Though, that said, keep in mind that these values get CHANGED when you use `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Which makes little sense to do this globally - you should only do it on the specific value you use in your query, *when you use it* .

Comment: You do not want to add magic quotes back to your PHP script. This is a very bad idea which will break your code. Use prepared statements!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are using  `mysqli_real_escape_string` instead of  `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['data'])` its required two parameter.`mysqli_real_escape_string()` is ok to use but if you want to be safe from `sql injection` you should use `PDO prepare statement`.See below insert query.

```
$prov_id = $_POST['prov_id'];
$practice_name = $_POST['prov_id'];

$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=xxxx;dbname=xxxx;", "xxxx", "xxxx"); //database connection
 $statement = $connection->prepare('INSERT INTO practices(prov_id,practice_name) VALUES (:prov_id,:practice_name)');

        $statement->bindParam(':prov_id', $prov_id);
        $statement->bindParam(':practice_name', $practice_name_data);
        // etc.

        $statement->execute();
```

Comment: `mysqli` also supports prepared statements.